# django image storage cdn

Tags: django, django-views, cdn, django-apps, rackspace

I have been using rackspace CDN for the last few months with django-imagekit and django-cumulus.

And I am not really happy with the results.

I seem to get load of errors because of timeouts etc.

```
 File "/www/django_test1/omu2/src/python-cloudfiles/cloudfiles/connection.py", line 347, in get_container
   return Container(self, container_name, count, size)

 File "/www/django_test1/omu2/src/python-cloudfiles/cloudfiles/container.py", line 83, in __init__
   self._fetch_cdn_data()

 File "/www/django_test1/omu2/src/python-cloudfiles/cloudfiles/utils.py", line 43, in decorator
   return f(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/www/django_test1/omu2/src/python-cloudfiles/cloudfiles/container.py", line 90, in _fetch_cdn_data
   response = self.conn.cdn_request('HEAD', [self.name])

 File "/www/django_test1/omu2/src/python-cloudfiles/cloudfiles/connection.py", line 151, in cdn_request
   self.cdn_connection.request(method, path, data, headers)

 File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 898, in request
   self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)

 File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 915, in _send_request
   self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)

 File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 802, in putrequest
   raise CannotSendRequest()

CannotSendRequest
```

What can you guys recommend? S3?

Comment: Technically speaking, S3 is only a storage solution. CloudFront (which uses S3) is Amazon's CDN solution.

Comment: you may also try [jare.io](http://www.jare.io), a free and instant CDN (based on AWS CloudFront)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amazon cloudfront has been great for serving video for us.  Check it here:
http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

You can use the boto package to integrate with it.

Check another example here:
http://www.peterbe.com/plog/hosting-django-static-images-with-amazon-cloudfront-cdn

Comment: Add to that django-storages solution, which abstracts all of the storage engines issues away, and your job is virtually done for you.